# Mechanically damaged aluminium electrolyte capacitor - is it very toxic?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, aluminium

I mechanically opened a aluminium electrolyte capacitor and I am afraid now if anything could happen to me.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: I think you're fine. Don't open chips that contain beryllium oxide, a white ceramic material that is thermally conductive but electrically insulative. Now that stuff is toxic (specifically the beryllium). Or batteries.

Comment: Anyone know if this guy is still alive? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141969/i-just-blew-a-capacitor-now-what/

Comment: You sound very worried. Please don't worry. Just use the normal precautions like everyone is saying. Wash your hands with soap and water after handling the capacitor.

Comment: The only kind of capacitor you really need to worry about are the really old (pre-1977 in North America) oil-filled ones that may contain PCBs (**P**oly**C**hlorinated **B**iphenyls) which are carcinogenic & dioxin-like.

Comment: The PCB it was mounted on is probably more dangerous.

Comment: I've blown up tons of caps.   Haven't died yet!    Wouldn't recommend eating it.

Answer (score 6):

From: Cornell Dubilier

Avoid ingestion, contact with the skin or eyes, and avoid prolonged inhalation.

In the case of electrolyte contact to skin, immediately rinse the exposed area with soap and water. If electrolyte contacts eyes, flush for 10 minutes with running water and seek medical attention. If vapors are present, ventilate the room. Smoke from burning electrolyte is irritating but does not contain dioxins or similar toxic substances. Seek medical attention if any symptoms persist. An SDS (Safety Data Sheet) is available for the electrolyte solvent base material.

Comment: Thank you very much, and what happens if somebody swallow it? because it is just a very small amount of electrolyte.

Comment: And how can be the vapors presented?

Comment: @MatúšBagin Have you been eating capacitors?

Comment: No just asking if yes.

Comment: The electrolyte is not very toxic, but it will make you sick if you swallow enough of it. If you just touched a small amount of it you should have no reason to worry. At room temperature, there would not be much vapor. A capacitor that overheats in a live circuit will release some vapor. I have seen large capacitors overheat and explode. I and others in the room had no ill effects.

Comment: It was only in the normal temperature room and the capacitor was about 1cm high so I do not need to ventilate the room?

Comment: No. You probably wouldn't need to ventilate the room unless you could smell or see vapor or smoke.

Comment: "Asking for a friend."

Comment: Last time somebody mentioned eating caps, I asked if that was the only thing on their plate     ;)